# Caching large files in ram

Tags: windows-7, video, cache, ramdisk, swap-file

I have 4K Video files, which are slow and jerky when played from a HDD.
They play flawlessly from an SSD, but my SSD has a limited lifespan, so I don't want to use it playing large temporary files.

Is there any utility that is capable of caching them in RAM, and does not use the swap file? (I have 32 GB RAM, and the files are 4/8 GB in size)

I have considered to make a RAM disk, but I would prefer a simpler solution if available.

The OS is Windows 7 64 bit.
GPU is an RTX 2060 6GB. I wish a video player were capable of storing the file on the GPU RAM.

Comment: A RAM disk is the simple solution. Also, research SSD lifespan. Its a lot longer then most people think. SSDs last many years in heavy server use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @davidgo about a RAM disk being the best option in your case. I use ImDisk (sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit): it's easy to install and set up.

With the amount of RAM you have, you can dedicate at least 6 to 8GB of it to the RAM disk without slowing down your PC.

You should set all your Temp folders in the RAM disk (there's a dedicated button in the GUI for that), use 64KB as cluster size instead of the default value, choose AWE, non-dynamic RAM, and you're good to go.